# About ICE-Chat Demo build

Tags: ice

when i use VS2012 Express nmake the build  about  Ice-Chat(1.4.0)(http://www.zeroc.com/chat/download.html), i always get the error:

```
ChatRoom.obj : error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl IceInternal::Cpp11FnCallbackNC::Cpp11FnCallbackNC(class std::function<void __cdecl(class IceUtil::Exception const &)> const &,class std::function<void __cdecl(bool)> const &)" (__imp_??0Cpp11FnCallbackNC@IceInternal@@QEAA@AEBV?$function@$$A6AXAEBVException@IceUtil@@@Z@std@@AEBV?$function@$$A6AX_N@Z@3@@Z)
ChatServer.obj : error LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl IceInternal::Cpp11FnCallbackNC::Cpp11FnCallbackNC(class std::function<void __cdecl(class IceUtil::Exception const &)> const &,class std::function<void __cdecl(bool)> const &)" (__imp_??0Cpp11FnCallbackNC@IceInternal@@QEAA@AEBV?$function@$$A6AXAEBVException@IceUtil@@@Z@std@@AEBV?$function@$$A6AX_N@Z@3@@Z)
```

what should i do? i have import the include files and  libs ,but don't work. I want to know Cpp11FnCallbackNC is belong to which lib.

Comment: Excuse me, what?! Please use some formatting and be concrete about your problem

Comment: I'm sorry ,this  is my fault.I reedit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's the answer to this:

When ICE is installed, say version 3.5.0, to

```
${ICEDIR}
```

you have the following directories:

```
for VS 2010:
${ICEDIR}/lib
for VS 2010 x64:
${ICEDIR}/lib/x64
for VS 2012:
${ICEDIR}/lib/vc110
for VS 2012 x64:
${ICEDIR}/lib/vc110/x64
```

In your case you likely added the wrong library path

Comment: yes,you are right! this error is  disappeared.But got the  new error:Application can not start properly (0xc000007b). Before this there is another error:lost the  glacier235.dll,when i put the glacier235.dll in the windows/system32，it's ok.but put in windows/syswow64 it's not correct.

Comment: The best you can do is to set the PATH variable in system properties to include the corresponding lib directory that you used to find the right libraries. If you are working on your own project, probably using CMake or some other tool, remember to NOT mix debug and release libraries from ICE. It will save you from a lot of pain...